# ServiceStack keep a long-live connection and send response asynchronously

Tags: servicestack

I have a client app which monitors the changes in real-time by establishing a long-live HTTP connection to server.

In ASP.NET WebAPI, the server can take use `PushStreamContent` to keep the connection for a long time and send response once there is an update.

But in ServiceStack, seems there is no similar stuff.

I looked at the sample code of [Different ways of returning an ImageStream](https://gist.github.com/mythz/2321702)
`IStreamWriter.WriteTo` method is only called once, and I can't use `async` IO operation to avoid blocking server thread.

Is there a way to send progressive response to client asynchronously?

here is sample code in WebAPI which does the job

```
public static async Task Monitor(Stream stream, HttpContent httpContent, TransportContext transportContext)
{

    ConcurrentQueue<SessionChangeEvent> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<SessionChangeEvent>();
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Action<SessionChangeEvent> callback = (evt) =>
    {
    queue.Enqueue(evt);
    tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    };
    OnSessionChanged += callback;
    try
    {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(string.Empty);
        await sw.FlushAsync();
        await stream.FlushAsync();

        for (; ; )
        {

        Task task = tcs.Task;
        await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(15000));

        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            SessionChangeEvent e;
            while (queue.TryDequeue(out e))
            {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(json);
            }

            task.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            // write an empty line to keep the connection alive
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(string.Empty);
        }
        await sw.FlushAsync();
        await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    OnSessionChanged -= callback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to a long-running connection is exactly what [Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) does. You can look at the implementation for [ServerEventsHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/109ad2a8853dcc569c5c6a9f52873e550dfd0ca1/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L102) or [ServerEventsHeartbeatHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/109ad2a8853dcc569c5c6a9f52873e550dfd0ca1/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L239) to see it's implemented in ServiceStack.

Basically it just uses a custom ASP.NET [IHttpAsyncHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be registered at the start of [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) with:

```
appHost.RawHttpHandlers.Add(req => req.PathInfo.EndsWith("/my-stream")
    ? new MyStreamHttpHandler()
    : null);
```

Where MyStreamHttpHandler is a custom HttpAsyncTaskHandler, e.g:

```
public class MyStreamHttpHandler : HttpAsyncTaskHandler
{
    public override bool RunAsAsync() { return true; }

    public override Task ProcessRequestAsync(
        IRequest req, IResponse res, string operationName)
    {
        //Write any custom request filters and registered headers
        if (HostContext.ApplyCustomHandlerRequestFilters(req, res))
            return EmptyTask;

        res.ApplyGlobalResponseHeaders();



        //Write to response output stream here, either by:
        res.OuputStream.Write(...);

        //or if need access to write to underlying ASP.NET Response
        var aspRes = (HttpResponseBase)res.OriginalResponse;
        aspRes.OutputStream...



        //After you've finished end the request with
        res.EndHttpHandlerRequest(skipHeaders: true);
        return EmptyTask;
    }
}
```

The `ApplyCustomHandlerRequestFilters()` and `ApplyGlobalResponseHeaders()` at the start gives other plugins a chance to validate/terminate the request or add any HTTP Headers (e.g. CorsFeature).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ServerEvents](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events). If I understood you right, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: that looks complicated :)  I am looking for an alternative framework to replace WebAPI and don't want to change the existing clients.  Would it be possible to perform operation on raw `OutputStream` in ServiceStack?  I tried that but failed, the object is disposed after a short while.

Comment: using ServerEvents would cause a change of the existing clients. "perform operation on raw outputstrem": I don't know.